# Como enviar esse XML para o webservice via PHP

Tags: php, libcurl, soap, certificado-digital, soapclient

Bom dia, tenho o seguinte problema:

Preciso retirar do site da prefeitura quais empresas emitiram nota esse mês.

Fiz os processos de instalar o certificado da prefeitura, e preciso da resposta desse xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <BuscarUsuario xmlns="http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/">
      <imu>string</imu>
      <cnpj>string</cnpj>
    </BuscarUsuario>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Parei aqui, não consigo enviar, muito menos passar o certificado, alguma dica de onde pesquisar isso?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, uma dica é pesquisar no projeto NFePHP, classe "Tools", ela faz uso do cURL e também de certificado digital, veja em https://github.com/nfephp-org/nfephp/blob/master/libs/NFe/ToolsNFe.php

Já em https://github.com/nfephp-org/nfephp/tree/master/libs/Common/Certificate você encontra exemplos de utilização de Certificado Digital. Por exemplo, acredito que você vai precisar de funções como a [openssl_pkcs12_read](http://php.net/openssl_pkcs12_read).